# ¿Cómo se llaman y cómo se definen las funciones con argumentos en bash?

Tags: linux, funciones, bash, parametros

A lo que me refiero no son a argumentos, sino a parámetros dentro de la zona de parámetros de la función, por ejemplo:

```
función('parámetro')
   {
       echo 'parámetro'
   }
    
función('parámetro')
```

Así como en cualquier otro lenguajes, vi que muchos lo explican pero con argumentos y no es lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1):

## Código solución rápida:

```
#!/bin/bash
funcion() {
    echo "$1"
}

funcion "hola"
```

salida:

```
hola
```

## Explicación

En `bash`, las funciones no se definen con parámetros, sino que las funciones son llamadas con argumentos. Esos argumentos dentro de la funcion se identifican con: `$1 $2 $3 $..n`   siguiendo por el orden de llamado...

Hay varias formas de definir las funciones, para ampliar y profundizar te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a la documentación oficial: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions